# Java File Path Not found for excel spreadsheet

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

So I am trying to print the first row of an excel file but for some odd reason it cannot find the file when it is on my desktop. Here is the code I have written:

```
public class ReadExcel {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        File fileName=new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "/Desktop/cc2017.xls");

        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(fileName)); //ERROR HERE

        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(0);

        System.out.println(sheet.getRow(0).toString());
    }
}
```

Here is the message shown on the console:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   \Desktop\cc2017.xls (The system cannot find the path specified)
>         at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
>         at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
>         at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
>         at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
>         at ReadExcel.main(ReadExcel.java:14)

The Line that the error points to is:

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(fileName));
```

Here is evidence that the file exists:

[image: cc2017.xls File]]

You can see that I have a simple file path and the file is an excel file with data on it but for some reason it is not being discovered. Any suggestions are appreciated thanks.

Comment: Please specify the OS that you are using.

Comment: A file not found expection

Comment: I am asking you about the operating system that you are using (Windows, Linux, iOS, etc)

Comment: oh sorry I'm using Windows 10

Comment: Ok, So you need the actual path of the file.  As in, D:/DavidFiles/testing.xlsx 
Like this. so if your file is on desktop then the path would be something like 
C://Users/<username>/Desktop/cc2017.xls

Comment: @DavidGardener: did you already try to double your slash characters (or use double backslashes)?

Comment: Yes I've tried that

Answer (score 1):

The way you provided the path, the application is looking in its working directory, like if your `workspace` is in `E:/Workspace/Your App` then the application is looking for the file in `E:/Workspace/Your App/Desktop/cc2017.xls`.

Use this one to get your file from Deskop

```
new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "/Desktop/cc2017.xls")
```

**Update in your code**

```
//NPOIFSFileSystem fs = new NPOIFSFileSystem(new File("cc2017.xls"));

        String fileName="/Desktop/cc2017.xls";
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), fileName))); //ERROR HERE

        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(0);

        System.out.println(sheet.getRow(0).toString());
```

> A sample program to test

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    String fileName = "/Desktop/cc2017.xls";
    File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), fileName);
    System.out.println("file: " + file);
    System.out.println("file exists: " + file.exists());
    HSSFWorkbook hssfWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));
    HSSFSheet sheet = hssfWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);
    HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(0);
    System.out.println(row.toString());
}
```

I created the file on my desktop with same name and look the output I got

```
file: C:\Users\CHIRAG GUPTA\Desktop\cc2017.xls
file exists: true
org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow@35f983a6
```

Comment: I have now changed the path to the correct path in my question but I am still getting the same error

Comment: file: C:\Users\User\Desktop\cc2017.xls
file exists: false
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\User\Desktop\cc2017.xls (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at ReadExcel.main(ReadExcel.java:16)

Comment: This is strange because the file is there

Comment: Please add the full path here by clicking `URL bar` of windows

Comment: Thanks for the help it works now. The reason why it was not working properly is because the file should be in the eclipse project in the file system and this is where the project points.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the file and check the absolute path. and use that in your program. 
As in, D:/DavidFiles/testing.xlsx Like this.

so if your file is on desktop then the path would be something like C://Users//Desktop/cc2017.xls